# How to get current block in observer?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I want get current block in my observer, for example I have observe event

```
        <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
            <observers>
                <mycompany_category_list_collection>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>mycompany/category</class>
                    <method>sendProductImpressionAfterLoad</method>
                </mycompany_category_list_collection>
            </observers>
        </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
```

this is event dispath in block reder category....
I can get this block class, name, file, type or other information for help me indetification this block in my method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try your stuff with below example:

```
public function coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

 $block = $observer->getBlock();

if($block instanceof Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager) {
        $collection = $block->getCollection();
        $pages = $block->getPages();
    }

}
```

Comment: edit your answer, this is good idea, you genius, thanks I try this and mark you answer as correct after, sorry for my English.

Comment: Yes is answer help me resolve my trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Use bellow  code in your `observer.php` file

```
public function sendProductImpressionAfterLoad($observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    /*get Block class*/
    echo get_class($block);
    /*get Block name */
    echo $block->getName()
   /*get Block type*/
    echo $type = $block->getType();
}
```

Comment: `getEvent()->getBlock()` return `null` because `Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_product_list_collection', array(
            'collection' => $this->_getProductCollection()
        ));` event not dispath block...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the block that dispatches the event `catalog_block_product_list_collection`.
The event is dispatched like this

```
 Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_product_list_collection', array(
    'collection' => $this->_getProductCollection()
 ));
```

There is no reference passed to the observer about who dispatches it.
Only the collection is passed on.
You should try to observe the block rendering if you want block specific actions.

Comment: I know but I can use other observer as say @Pallavi

Comment: @Naumov. Yep. you should take that approach.